# loop over elements in div

Tags: javascript, html

New to javascript so please be kind.

I am trying to loop over a all the elements in the "wrapper" class to show each element for x amount of time. This code just shows all elements at once.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
  <title>Cell One</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="x" id="inner">
      <p>Test</p>
    </div>
    <div class="x" id="inner">
      <p>Testing</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="./main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript

```
var divOne = document.getElementsByClassName('x')
console.log(divOne.length)


for (let i=0, len = divOne.length; i < len; i++) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    divOne[i].style.display = 'none';
  }, 5000)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is due to below code

```
  setTimeout(() => {
    divOne[i].style.display = 'none';
  }, 5000)
```

Which will make all the element hide after 5000 millseconds,so you need to set them sepeartely

```js
var divOne = document.getElementsByClassName('x')


for (let i=0, len = divOne.length; i < len; i++) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    for(let j=0;j<len;j++){
        if(j==i){
            divOne[j].style.display = 'inline-block';
         }else{
            divOne[j].style.display = 'none';
         }
     }
  }, 5000*i)
}
```

```css
.x{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
  <title>Cell One</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="x" id="inner">
      <p>Test</p>
    </div>
    <div class="x" id="inner">
      <p>Testing</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="./main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This worked! Thank you. Follow up question. What if I want that to repeat? I tried the setTimeout at the end of the function but it doesn't repeat.

Comment: @DadTheGamer you need to use `setInterval()` to do it and the code needs to be changed

Comment: I created a function for the loop. Does the setInterval() go inside the function?

Comment: @DadTheGamer in my opinion, the loop should outside it

Answer (score 0):

The setTimeout waits the 5000ms specified. The reason to hide all elements at the same time is that **this code have created all Timeouts with same executing time, making all Timeouts runs at the same time**.

The solution is when create the Timeout, pass the ms duration major of the previous, can be done like this:

```js
for (let i=0, len = divOne.length; i < len; i++) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    divOne[i].style.display = 'none';
  }, 5000 * (i+1))
}
```

Look at the second parameter of setTimeout, we add the 5000ms multiplicated by index of loop + 1 (because the var i starts with 0).

Try code:

```js
var divOne = document.getElementsByClassName('x')
console.log(divOne.length)


for (let i=0, len = divOne.length; i < len; i++) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    divOne[i].style.display = 'none';
  }, 5000 * (i+1))
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
  <title>Cell One</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="x" id="inner">
      <p>Test</p>
    </div>
    <div class="x" id="inner">
      <p>Testing</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

To loop over a all the elements in the "wrapper" class to show each element for x amount of time
Lets try this code

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
  <title>Cell One</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="x" id="inner">
      <p>Test</p>
    </div>
    <div class="x" id="inner">
      <p>Testing</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="./main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

here is a JavaScript code which will iterate loop over class name x and hide them with x amount of time one by one

Javascript

```
    let x = document.querySelectorAll('.x')
  
    for (let i=0; i < x.length; i++)
     {
        setTimeout(() => {x[i].style.display = 'none';},5000*i+1)
     }
```